# can't draw an SFML sprite when sprite has a negative position

Tags: drawing, sprite, sfml

Whenever I try to draw an SFML sprite with a negative position, the sprite will not be drawn to the screen. I have tried with and without a view applied to the window, but the sprite is not rendered either time.

I have a sprite with a texture on it (size 32*64). I try drawing in at position (-1,-1) but it will not work. Is this intentional behaviour. If so how would I go about drawing sprites with negative positions.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("texture.png")) {
    std::cout << "Error rendering Object";
    return 0;
}

sf::Sprite Sprite;
Sprite.setTexture(texture);

Sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(-5, -5));
```

> And draw sprite > window.draw(Sprite);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had some confusing mix-ups with signed and unsigned ints. This caused the sprites to be unable to be drawn in negative positions. Please check signed-unsigned types if this error occured for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).